# the zoom is not clear in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

i created buttons to zoom to particular countries. However when i clicked the button,Singapore it navigate to Singapore but i cant see exactly the Singapore country. [image]

So i wanted a better image.[image]

Here is my code below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Use correct character set. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>My Work</title>
  <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">

  </script>
  <style>
      @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
      html, body, #cesiumContainer {
          width: 98%; height: 98%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="cesiumContainer">
    <button type="button" class="cesium-button" onclick = "zoomToSingapore();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Please click me if you want to zoom to Singapore">Zoom To Singapore</button>
    <button type="button" class="cesium-button" onclick = "zoomToMalaysia();" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Please click me if you want to zoom to Malaysia">Zoom To Malaysia</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cesiumContainer" style="position:absolute;top:24px;right:24px;width:38px;height:38px;"></div>
  <script>

    viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
        timeline: false,
        navigationHelpButton: false,
        infoBox: false
    });
    function zoomToSingapore()
    {
        var singapore = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(103.851959, 1.290270);
        viewer.camera.lookAt(singapore, new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 4200000.0));
    }
    function zoomToMalaysia()
    {
        var malaysia = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(101.9758, 4.2105);
        viewer.camera.lookAt(malaysia, new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 4200000.0));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question, if i click Singapore, it will zoom to Singapore just like the second image which i have attached to this question.. What do i need to zoom just like the last image???Can you please help me?? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your height is too high.  Try changing `4200000.0` to `42000.0`.

*Edit:*  Here's a more complete code example.  This one turns on labels, so you can see the borders.  Paste this code into [Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/) and run it with F8.

```
var imagery = Cesium.createDefaultImageryProviderViewModels();

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    imageryProviderViewModels: imagery,
    selectedImageryProviderViewModel: imagery[1]
});

var height = 50000;
var singapore = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(103.85, 1.33, height);

viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination: singapore,
    duration: 0
});
```

Above, I get the default list of imagery providers, and pre-select the one with labels turned on.  Then I fly to a point 50km above Singapore, using `duration: 0` to snap the camera there.

Comment: oh so the height is the problem.. Is it possible to zoom to singapore just like typing singapore in the search box

Comment: ur code work... wow I think i do not understand the purpose of Cesium.matrix4.identity. would you mind explaining me more about this as i do not understand from the documentation

Comment: Oops, that `Matrix4.IDENTITY` thing was copy-pasted from the Geocoder [source](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.36/Source/Widgets/Geocoder/GeocoderViewModel.js#L331-L337) I was looking at.  You don't need it, and I removed it from my answer.